# Invalid Character Found In Text

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I have 10 Windows XP Machines that have a Firebird .fdb database installed.

The applications were all working fine until the last few days where one of the .executables have started giving an error 'An Invalid Character Found In Text Content'.

This is only occuring on a Windows XP terminal. After transferring the database/ application on a windows 10 or windows 7 PC, it works fine.

Wondering if someone knows much about this issue and could point me in the right direction to fix it?

Comment: Without seeing your code or at least the SQL queries (and the table definitions) this is impossible to answer.

Comment: _"An Invalid Character Found In Text Content'"_ is not a Firebird error, so this is likely a problem in your application. You should contact the author or vendor of that program.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your help.
The problem was with the MSXML 4.0 Service Pack 3. The application started working after I deleted the above.